# How to rename a directory with wildcards in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm trying the following:

```
rename "*12" "12"
```

I get the error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Is it that we cannot use wildcard characters in quotes? if yes how do i use them with 
quotes?

[image]

Comment: Please explain better your problem. Type the command and the scenario pls.

Comment: When creating a question it's best to have a title that accurately describes your problem, to demonstrate what you are attempting and any error messages you get. You should also describe what you are trying to achieve. Without this information questions are incredibly difficult to answer. Please see [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15781414/revisions) to see the differences between your original question and what I have changed.

Comment: yeah, thanks!
i was just about to edit it when u edited it.
thanks anyways.

Comment: Strange. Should work.

Comment: It seems to depend on what files exist. I get a "syntax error" if the wildcard (param1) exist as a directory, not as a file. If you were renaming files, it would work. Probably this is because wildcards are handled differently when applied to a directory, as opposed to a file.

Comment: Yet it works for some cases with directories, too. This is strange as long as one does not know what´s going on, indeed.

Comment: `rename` does work for directories since MS-DOS 2.11 (Oct 1983)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rename` with wildcards only works on files, to rename a directory, use `move`;

```
C:\Temp>echo "test" > olle12  
C:\Temp>mkdir olle13
C:\Temp>rename "*12" 12
C:\Temp>rename "*13" 13
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Temp>move "*13" 13
C:\Temp\olle13
    1 dir(s) moved.
C:\Temp>dir
 Directory of C:\Temp

2013-04-03  10:01                 9 12
2013-04-03  10:01    <DIR>          13
```

Comment: Slight clarification to Endoro's comment: Rename of folder without wildcard works. Rename of folder with wildcard does not work.

Comment: yeah that^ pretty much sums it up. Thanks everybody.

Comment: @dbenham Sorry, you're right, I wasn't clear about the wildcard condition. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rename also works on folders properly:

```
ren "the god of high school 12" 12
```

.. or you use a for loop:

```
for /d %i in (*12) do ren "%~i" 12
```