# Batch - Rename Folder matching pattern

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

if %ThisService_filerestoreoption% == 1 (
if exist "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%" rmdir /s /q "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%"
ROBOCOPY D:\file-backups\%ThisUser_Username%\Mission\%ThisService_mapname% %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname% /minage:%ThisService_filerestoreage% /maxage:%ThisService_filerestoreage% /e
ren "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%_*" "%ThisService_mapname%"
ROBOCOPY D:\file-backups\%ThisUser_Username%\Server %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons dayz_server_*.pbo /minage:%ThisService_filerestoreage% /maxage:%ThisService_filerestoreage%
if exist "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server.pbo" DEL "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server.pbo"
ren "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server_*.pbo" "dayz_server.pbo"
)

if %ThisService_filerestoreoption% == 2 (
ROBOCOPY D:\file-backups\%ThisUser_Username%\Server %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons dayz_server_*.pbo /minage:%ThisService_filerestoreage% /maxage:%ThisService_filerestoreage%
if exist "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server.pbo" DEL "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server.pbo"
ren "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%@DayZ_Epoch_Server\Addons\dayz_server_*.pbo" "dayz_server.pbo"
)
```

I need to be able to rename the folder within the first if statment:

```
ren "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%_*" "%ThisService_mapname%"
```

The problem is that it wont find the folder matching this pattern, If it was a file it would work no problem, but is this even possible to do with a folder?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a directory with wildcards in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781414/how-to-rename-a-directory-with-wildcards-in-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

The REN command is horribly documented, especially with regard to how it handles wildcards. I've experimented extensively and come up with the rules: See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) over on SuperUser.

Unfortunately, the REN command will not rename folders with any wildcards in the source or target names.

In looking at your code, it seems you are confident that the source mask will never match more than one folder. I'll assume you are correct.

You could do the following to get around the problem:

```
for /d %%F in ("%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%_*") do ren "%%F" "%ThisService_mapname%"
```

Another option is my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that renames files or folder via regular expression search and replace on the name.

```
call jren "^.*" "%ThisService_mapname%" /d /p "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions" /fm "%ThisService_mapname%_*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `move` instead of `ren`

```
move "%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%_*" "%ThisService_mapname%"
```

Note that if there are any files that match that wildcard, `move` and `ren` will rename the files and leave the directories alone.  @dbenham's `FOR /D` solution will still work in this case.

Comment: Good idea, but that will fail if there also exist files that begin with `%ThisService_mapname%_*` - it will move (rename) the files instead of the folder. Perhaps not an issue.

Comment: Point.  But so will ren, so I assumed OP solved that problem already

Comment: Note that REN will never raname a folder if a wildcard exists in the source or target mask. So there could never be ambiguity between a file or folder when using REN. The same is not true for MOVE.

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps easier-to-use solution is a command-line JScript script I wrote a while back:

[Windows IT Pro: Rename Files by Using Regular Expressions](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/rename-files-using-regular-expressions)

Usage is:

```
[cscript] Renamer.js <directory> [...] [/f:<str>] [/r:<str>] [/o:<d|f|df>] [/c]
[/p] [/s] [/t]

<directory> - Specify one or more directory names on the command line
/f:<str> - Regular expression to find in file/directory names (default=space)
/r:<str> - Replacement string (default=_)
/o:<d|f|df> - What to rename? d=directories, f=files, df=both (default=f)
/c - Case-sensitive pattern matching (don't ignore case)
/p - Prompt to rename each file/directory
/s - Recurse through subdirectories
/t - Test mode: Only display what will be renamed

USE THIS SCRIPT WITH EXTREME CAUTION. It can potentially render a system
unbootable by renaming system files/directories, and it can break applications
by renaming critical files/directories.

The script does not test whether a directory or a file's new name is valid
before attempting to rename it, so test mode (/t) may report inaccurate results
if a new name is not valid.
```

Comment: Don't be dissuaded by the downvote. The script works quite well; I have used it for many years now.